# JSP and HTML synchronization issue

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-tags

I am facing a problem. The code is as follows:

```
<% for (3 times){%>
    <div> one 
        <table> two <table>
    <% if(true){%> </div> <%}%>
<%}%>
```

The output is coming as:

```
<div>one</div>
<table>two</table>
<div>one
    <table>two</table>
</div>
<div>one
    <table>two</table>
</div>
```

As you can see, the first `<div>` has completed before the `<table>` started. Then the later `<div>` is correct. I don't know the reason. Could you please explain?

Comment: Show the actual code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't mess up java and HTML code, move to the MVC pattern.

Comment: The output you have shown could never have been produced by the pseudo code you have written.